# Installing Ubuntu from a Flash Drive Using Refit

Tags: system-installation

Is this possible? I don't have a blank disc larger than 700 mb at the moment.

Comment: Maybe you can use install Lubuntu, which only requires less than 700 MB, instead, and then just install the `ubuntu-desktop` package. That will install all the necessary packages and software settings of a true Ubuntu system.

Comment: The Refit project is no longer actively maintained. You might have better luck with Refind http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: Short answer : Yes.  Look at the instructions on the rEFInd page http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program like Unetbootin to make a bootable pendrive with a *.iso file of your election. You need just a pendrive with enough storage and to configure your motherboard to boot from USB.

Comment: UNetbootin support is not really great for OSX (not a lot of support documents). A program like rEFIt is better for OSX as it is specifically for systems using EFI (Mac systems). There is not a "normal" BIOS for Macs so it is harder to boot from a USB, and UNetbootin can cause some issues, and/or not work correctly.